# Bluetooth headphones not connecting to my pc. Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: bluetooth, headphones, 20.04

Bluetooth headphones not connecting to my pc. This video shows the full details. It connects for a few seconds but then it disconnects, I also tried blueman app but, I even tried bluesman app but it says connection failed :resource temporarily unavailable. I am new to Linux so please help me out.
1)i am using skulcandy sesh truly wireless headphones
2)after lspci code

> 00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
>   00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
>   00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
>   00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Thermal Subsystem (rev 0b)
>   00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
>   00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
>   00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
>   00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
>   00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
>   00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev e4)
>   00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev e4)
>   00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
>   00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
>   00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
>   00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series Thermal (rev 04)
>   07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
>   0d:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430 / Radeon 520 Mobile] (rev 83)
>   13:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter

Comment: 1) Make & model of Bluetooth headphones so we can see what profiles they support. 2) Make & model part number (from serial number sticker) or motherboard model # 3) Result of running _sudo lspci -knn | grep Net -A3 && sudo lsusb -v_ ; highlight resulting text & copy it with Ctrl-Shift-C  Come back here, click [edit], & paste it in to your question along w/ answers to 1) and 2) so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you.   Background: https://askubuntu.com/search?q=bluetooth+headphones